# Disable escape key in Inventor

Tags: c#, autodesk-inventor

I have an addin with userinterface (usercontrol in a dockable window) that launches a command that takes a long time to run in Inventor and I don't want it to be possible to get interrupted by an user pressing the escape key (ascii 27). I've tried to set  `UserInteractionDisabled = true` but it looks like the escape key slips throught the net.
Also tried to subscribe to the keypress event, but no luck either.

Any one who can tell me how to block/disable the escape key?

Answer (score 0):

How do you start your command? Probably your addin should define an own Inventor-command that will run without the possibilty to be interrupted via escape.
I would think, that the keypress event will work for your usercontrol only, so that won't do.

Comment: Paul, thanks for the answer but actually I'm starting a proces via a button click in the addin. In this proces a lot of individual Inventor API calls are performed and it's this proces that I don't want to be cancelled by pressing the ESC key.

Answer (score 0):

I've got an Inventor app with a command which takes about 25 min. to execute. It is not possible to cancel this command with the ESC key. I defined the command within a ribbon tab via Application.CommandManager.ControlDefinitions.AddButtonDefinition (that is what I meant by Inventor-command). May be your form itself proceeds the ESC key and stops running, but this is a guess only.